# How to hide Listview's ScrollBars with AppCompat Style

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollbar

I have several `ListViews` in my apps, and I write almost the same code in everyone, but some have `ScrollBar`, they all have `android:scrollBars = "none"` and it does not work.

So what is the problem? How can I hide the ScrollBars?

**layout file:**

```
 <com.zuanbank.android.widgets.RefreshListView 
  android:id="@+id/list_view"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/main_bg"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:scrollbars="none"
  app:init_footer="true"
  app:init_header="false">

</com.zuanbank.android.widgets.RefreshListView>
```

**And my style:**

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">   </style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/activityAnimation</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/blue_00a0ea</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorControlActivated</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/blue_00a0ea</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Could you please post your layout file?

Comment: So you're not using the default `ListView`? Is this a custom lib? Could you show me where did you get it? Perhaps this custom implementation ignores the flags, so that's why it's not working...

Comment: No,I define a custom ListView can pull to load more or refresh,it extends android ListView.https://github.com/msdx/RefreshListView here is the resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the xml is not working, try to hide it programmatically.

```
listview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false); 
listview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Anyways, the xml way should be working... As it's stated on [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars).

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

**Edit:** As it seems, you're not using the default `ListView`. One option would be for you to rollback to the default implementation, and wrap it around the `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/srl_refresh">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lv_data"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Then on your `Fragment` or `Activity`, do this:

```
srl_refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.srl_refresh);
srl_refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        doRefresh(); // Call your refresh method here.
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry , it is a spell mistake,actually， i  do whiteandroid:scrollbars="none"

Comment: sorry , it is a spell mistake,actually， i  do white `android:scrollbars="none"`, and i have tried `listview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false); 
listview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);` it did not work neither.

Comment: Are you using `ScrollView`?

Comment: no.it works before I add supportv7 lib in my project.After that, it shows a different scrollbar,And I can never hide it.

Comment: What happens if you call `isVerticalScrollBarEnabled()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot.Now i'm sure it is my customed-listview's problem,I'll find why.And if I don't have any idea to resolve it,I'll try yours.because I have a lot such listviews in my project.

Comment: Thank u very much, I have a `setFastScrollEnabled(true)` in my listview,So  it the xml and java ways can not work